# Error:XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

Hello I have problem with that code 
Gradle 'Revir3D' project refresh failed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="DEFAULT_WRAPPED" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/app" />
          </set>
        </option>
        <option name="resolveModulePerSourceSet" value="false" />
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: Does one of your `$X$` parameters evaluate to a string that contains an [**XML character that must be escaped**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)?

Comment: no it is just clean fresh code i just added some buttons on menu and connection to the database